# How to get average/mean with mapping in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, mean

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

| Birthyear | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1992 | 2 |
| 1993 | 2.2 |
| 1992 | 3 |
| 1993 | 2.5 |
| 1994 | 2.4 |
| 1993 | 1.8 |
| 1994 | 2.1 |

Note: This is an example, I have +100k of rows and years

I want to get a new DataFrame in which I have every year and its average weight, mapping automatically every year because it would take a lot of work and code lines to do it manually.

| Birthyear | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| 1992 | 2.5 |
| 1993 | 2.1 |
| 1994 | 2.25 |

I've tried mapping, which worked before to use a reference table, but didn't work for this

```
dfaverage = df

dfaverage['Weight'] = dfaverage['Birthyear'].map(df.set_index('Year')[df['Weight'].mean])
```

**TypeError**: unhashable type: 'DataFrame'

Any ideas on how can I make this idea work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
dfaverage.groupby('Birthyear')['Weight'].mean().to_frame()
```